# auth=true at mongodb 32Bit Linux not working

Tags: linux, mongodb, authentication, configuration, 32-bit

I'm using mongodb on 64Bit and 32Bit Linux servers with same configuration, where the option `auth=true` is set in both config files.

While the 64Bit system required an authentication to run commands like `show users` or `show collections`, the 32Bit version gives you all the requested informations without running `db.auth()` before.

It looks like, the 32 Bit version ignores the `auth=true` option at the config file.

So: how can I enable auth for mongodb running on an 32Bit system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 32bit version should support authentication just fine. But it is possible that:

- It uses a different configuration file (use: `-f /etc/mongodb.conf` as option when starting MongoDB) **or** you can specify `--auth` on the command line
- Because the databases are empty and no user is setup at all, authentication is not required. As soon as you add a user, it will then require `db.auth()`.
- You don't have a user on the `admin` database defined. Without this, you can always connect on localhost.

Comment: mongo uses the right config file. I tried the following: `mongod --auth --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb` but: still no `db.auth()` required. There are 3 existing users and one document at one collection. All that information available without authentication.

Comment: you said: "Because the databases are empty and no user is setup at all." The users are setup up for a specific database, but mongo says: ` [conn1] note: no users configured in admin.system.users, allowing localhost access`. Does it mean: i have to add an additional user at the admin db?

Comment: Thank you, for that hint. +1 I'm not sure if that is the solution for me. I found the option, which enables auth for locahlost connects, as you can see at my answer. I will think about, which solution I will use.

Comment: That's not the solution, just a workaround. The correct way of doing this is adding an admin user.

Answer (score 0):

The point is, that authentication is disabled because there is no db users added, only users for a specific database. Connecting to this database using localhost results in an "auth"-free environment. (see for this also the answer from @Derick which point to a possible reason.)

To come back to the question:

> So: how can I enable auth for mongodb running on an 32Bit system?

The point is: the auth is active, but not for connects from localhost. To enable auth for connects from localhost, the following startup option is needed:

```
enableLocalhostAuthBypass=0
```

Comment: `Error parsing INI config file: unrecognised option 'enableLocalhostAuthBypass'` (v3.6.3, from ubuntu default package)

Answer (score 0):

I finished this,the role is necessary

```
db.createUser(
   {
user: "youloginname",
pwd: "123456",
roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```